# Find Value in Pivoted LookupTable

Tags: sql, pivot, lookup

I'm trying to figure out the best way to query from a pivoted lookup table.

Ideally, you'd have a look up table with 3 columns

```
min, max, value
 1,   2,   a
 2,   3,   b
 3,   4,   c
```

here you can write code to pull the correct output:

```
select value from table
where input >= min and input < max
```

so if input = 1.5, then value = a and if input = 2.5, value = b. As the rows are disjoint,

However, our table has to be constructed in the following manner as this is a janky one off situation.

```
1,2,3,4
a,b,c,-
```

How would I create a query that would find the value in this type of table?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: it is not clear what column names are and what values each holds

Comment: tables are not clear. pls write column's name and give us more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, our table has to be constructed in the following manner as
>   this is a janky one off situation.

You have two options:

Unpivot this table and then query from a result of this subquery 
in the same manner `SELECT value FROM ( subquery ) ...`:

```
SELECT 1 as min, 2 as max, "1" as value FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as min, 3 as max, "2" asvalue FROM table1
Union All
SELECT 3 as min, 4 as max, "3" asvalue FROM table1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b6b4d/2

```
| min | max | value |
|-----|-----|-------|
|   1 |   2 |     a |
|   2 |   3 |     b |
|   3 |   4 |     c |
```

You can create a view using the above query and run queries against this view.

---

Assumming that there is only 1 row in this table- build a queries like this one:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN input >=1 AND input < 2 THEN "1"
       WHEN input >=2 AND input < 3 THEN "2"
       WHEN input >=3 AND input < 4 THEN "3"
       END As value
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for a CASE WHEN statement

```
Select case when min >= 1 and max <3 then 'A'
            when min >= 2 and max <4 then 'B'
            when min >= 3 and max <5 then 'C'

       else NULL
       end Value

 From table
```

Hope this helps